# Show the previous and after N lines each for the matched lines?

Tags: powershell

The following command will show the lines match the pattern.

```
cat file.txt | select-string -pattern "..."
```

How to show the previous and after 3 lines each for the matched lines? (Like the `-C3` parameter of grep.) Also is it possible to print out the line number?

BTW, the command is much slower comparing with grep?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify the filename in the `-Path` parameter of `Select-String`, and use the `-Context` switch to specify the number of lines before and after to include.

```
select-string -path file.txt -pattern "..." -Context 1,3
```

The file name and line number will be included in the output

Comment: It works. One strange thing - it will return only one row and ignore the `-Content 10` parameter when it's piped to `| Out-Gridview`. (Tested on Powershell V2)

Comment: Those are matchinfo object, not simple strings.  If you want to pipe it to Out-GridView, you'll need to construct output strings using the .line, .context.postcontext, and .context.precontext properties of the objects.

Comment: How to use `.line`, `.context` and `.postcontext`? However, found that `| Out-File filename.txt` pipes all the lines though.

Comment: Start a new question for that, with some sample input to test with. That'll give you a chance to see multiple solutions from different people.

Comment: Created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606338/pipe-to-out-gridview-and-out-file-got-different-rows.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you only specify one number, it shows the lines before and after the match, i.e. -Content 3 shows 3 lines before and 3 lines after.