# Pipe to Out-GridView and Out-File got different rows?

Tags: powershell

The following command returns only one row (the parameter `-Context 10` is ignored.)

```
select-string -path file.txt -pattern "..." -Context 10 | Out-GridView
```

However, the following command create a file with all the lines.

```
select-string -path file.txt -pattern "..." -Context 10 | Out-File file2
```

Why there is a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Out-Gridview` consumes the entire `MatchInfo` object that `Select-String` outputs, and displays all of the properties of that object as columns. `Out-File` on the other hand basically performs the `ToString()` method on everything before it outputs it to a file, and for that kind of object when it converts to a string it outputs the line, and the context lines as well. If you want `Out-GridView` to do that you will have to pipe to Out-String and then to `Out-Gridview`.